# Traslating framebuffer

Tags: opengl, drawing, 2d, lwjgl

To learn opengl i'm trying to draw a little real-time line chart (about new 20.000 point/s is the goal)

I thinked I can optimize the thing if i don't clean all the framebuffer, but somehow traslate it on one direction, and then draw the new and missing step of the graph.

I can see it is possible to copy to a FBO needed area and then edit this FBO and then draw that result, but in the end it still need to copy all pixel

Comment: What's good with fbo's is that they could be larger than your screen, so that you may shift it smoothly along time, but a recurent blit will allways be required once the max width is reached.

Comment: That wa my fear. Maybe i can traslate the fbo using a shader?

Comment: That makes no sense to me...your shader will be clipped by your geometries, you may use them to scroll your trends. But one blit is reasonable for such a task...it's GPU blitting, parallelized, so nicely optimized...

Comment: @lesto: This sounds like a job for tiled rendering (the general concept), the way you are describing it. But on the other hand, 20k points/sec is chump change on modern GPUs and you can easily do this in real-time without any complicated optimization work. The best advice I can give you is to implement it in OpenGL first and then worry about whether or not you need to find a way to optimize it (my gut says you won't).

Comment: Already implemented using direct rendering, see https://github.com/MauroMombelli/lwjglChart/blob/master/src/fastchart/SeriePrinter.java, obviusly not a problem, but i will look into tiled just as study case